# Uni-directional association or Interface notation (UML)?

Tags: class, associations, uml, diagram

[image]

Either the above notation indicates Uni-Directional Association (both strong [solid lines] and weak [dotted lines]), or the notation is inconsistent with traditional UML and is trying to indicate an Interface with the dotted lines (without appropriate 'arrowheads'). What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1):

One simple look tells that the author has no idea of UML. Look at the dependency between `Part` and `Product`. Clearly it's the wrong way around. Further, an `abstract` class must be concretized somewhere, which is not the case (I guess the two lower associations should be generalizations). Ask the author what he wanted to say.

Comment: Believe it or not, this is an assignment from a fully accredited university.

Comment: Well, that doesn't change the flaws (not to say scrap) in that diagram.